# Stored procedure - to print my result from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

```
select count(*) as count
from [dbo].[DATA_received] where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_TIME  GETDATE()) <= 1
```

I want to run this in some frequency to check whether I am receiving data  in DB.

I want to write stored procedure where if my results 0 then ,"No data received"

If the count is >0 then it should print "Data received"

Comment: Print where? Do you plan to leave SSMS open forever and call this query in a loop until... when?

Comment: i will use this query in solarwinds for some monitoring purpose

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're going to make SolarWinds do something with this output or run it every minute, but there is absolutely no reason to count how many rows were added in the last minute if you only need to know whether at least one such row exists... and you really should never apply formulae like `DATEDIFF` to a column, it will force the query to scan the entire table every time:

```
SELECT MessageToPrint = CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.DATA_received
    WHERE DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, sysutcdatetime())
  ) THEN 'Data received.' ELSE 'No data received.' END;
```